# How do I get JBoss AS 7.2 to register my OSGi services when the bundle is loaded?

Tags: jboss, osgi, jboss7.x, blueprint-osgi

I have created a small sample project to have a reference implementation of OSGi with Spring (i.e. Blueprint), and I can get all bundles to install, resolve and start OK, but my service is not registered when the bundle starts.

I've made the entire project [available on github](https://github.com/tlycken/HelloOsgi) so you can take a look at the source - the jars output from the build are in the `artifacts` folder, but you can also build the project yourself by running `gradle assemble`.

As I've understood the Blueprint specification, and particularly [this guide](http://aries.apache.org/documentation/tutorials/blueprinthelloworldtutorial.html), there is no need for an activator class to register the services if the configuration files are in the right place - in my jar, I have the following under `OSGI-INF/blueprint/sillyservice.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

    <bean id="sillyService" class="se.sunstone.silly.service.ServiceImpl"
        init-method="startService">
    </bean>

    <service ref="helloservice"
        interface="com.sample.blueprint.helloworld.api.HelloWorldService" />
</blueprint>
```

When deploying this bundle, JBoss reports the bundle as ACTIVE.

When I then deploy the client bundle, there is an activator class that runs the following snippet to list *all* registered services:

```
ServiceReference[] refs = context.getAllServiceReferences(null, null);
if (refs != null) {
    logger.info(String.format("There are %s references", refs.length));

    for (ServiceReference ref : refs) {
        logger.info(ref);
    }
} else {
    logger.info("There are no registered services.");
}
```

A bunch of services that are registered by the OSGi framework inside JBoss are listed, but not my `SillyService`.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: If you want to deploy this in JBoss AS 7.2 yourself, you will also need to provide commons.logging (version info is in the build file). The OSGi Framework dependency is provided by JBoss.

Comment: Have you deployed the Blueprint Extender bundle?

Comment: @NeilBartlett: Not manually, no - and when I dig around in the config files and among the module and bundle jars I can't find it. So that's likely the culprit. However, I can't find any documentation on where to get the bundle, and how to add it to the JBoss config. Would you care to enlighten me? Do so in an answer, so that I may give you upvotes =)

Comment: I have no idea how to add it to the JBoss config as I don't use JBoss. I will tell you where to find the bundle though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable Blueprint functionality, you need to install a Blueprint Extender bundle. There are two implementations available: Apache Aries and Eclipse Gemini. I recommend Aries, which is available from http://aries.apache.org/

Comment: Is there a specific reason you prefere Aries' implementation over Eclipse's? I'm leaning towards using Gemini Blueprint, simply because it is available from ebr.springsource.com, so I can use my build tool to download all the required archives and their dependencies.

Comment: The Aries implementation is much more lightweight, and it is actually maintained by developers who care about it. The Gemini implementation was originally maintained by SpringSource but has essentially been abandoned after their move to VMware or Pivotal or whatever they're calling themselves this week ;-)

Comment: I took the Gemini route anyway, for now. Not having to dig through the internet to find all the jars was nice - it might be dead simple with the Aries implementation as well, but as long as this is working I'm not switching ;) Thanks for the help!